# PHP Error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in filename.php

Tags: php, html, php-parse-error

I have three buttons , Edit remove and view .. on view part i am trying to echo the row ID in order to fetch details . But i get this parse error .

Here is the Code :

```
 while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) { 
 $active = '';
 if($row['active'] == 1) {
    $active = '<label class="label label-success">Complete</label>';
 } else {
    $active = '<label class="label label-danger">Incomplete</label>'; 
 } 


 $actionButton = '
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-     toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"  data-target="#editMemberModal"  onclick="editMember('.$row['id'].')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a></li>
    <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeMemberModal" onclick="removeMember('.$row['id'].')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove</a></li>
    <li><a class="view_data"  type="button" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#dataModal" id="'.<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> View</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
    ';
```

Am facing this error on the dropdown menu third list .. class is view_data

Comment: Does the error give you a line number?

Comment: Yes , Am facing this error on the dropdown menu third list .. class is view_data

Comment: Just compare how you concatenate: `'.$row['id'].'` and `'.<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.` see any difference?!

Comment: Yeh, if this is already within a PHP tag (which it seems to be as you have a while loop, if statements and are assigning the string to a variable) then there is no need to put more PHP tags. Simply `.$row["id"].` should work.

Comment: i tried the above method  '.$row['id'].' .. the error gets resolved but its not fetching the data . in console it shows member_id:<?php echo 1; ?>;  but it should appear  member_id: 1 ; .. it is taking <?php echo ?> as a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your last li change it as per below:

```
<li><a class="view_data"  type="button" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#dataModal" id="' . $row['id'] . '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> View</a></li>
```

Also in above code ending `}` is missing at last

Comment: Thanks a ton .. i replaced the third list with your code and the error got resolved